# Assigning a DataFrame to a DataFrame Column works if the column already exists and doesn't otherwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to understand a weird interaction Pandas does when you assign a DataFrame to a column. Based on split-apply-combine methodology, sometimes a groupby apply returns a Pandas series (what I want) and sometimes it returns a DataFrame (if the groupby grouping is all one group).

I've tried to control for this because Pandas throws an error when you try to assign a DataFrame to a DataFrame column, so I try to assign and then stack the DataFrame if it throws an error.

However, I've discvored ANOTHER weird interaction which is that if the column that you're trying to assign already exists, the assignment works but just gives all NaNs (or sometimes I've seen one value other than NaN). If the column doesn't exist, the assignment throws an error as expected, and I've excepted for this to work correctly.

Can anyone explain this in a way that makes sense, so I know how to think about this in the future? The fix itself is relatively easy - I can just check if the intermediate result is a DataFrame or Series, but I thought Python thematically was generally supposed to be asking for forgiveness instead of checking for permission.

Here's my code and results:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type1': 'a', 'type2': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
  'index': range(8), 'arpi': np.random.normal(loc=10, size=8), 'cumarpi': np.random.randint(0,100,8)},
  columns=['type1', 'type2', 'index', 'arpi', 'cumarpi'])

print df

  type1 type2  index       arpi  cumarpi
0     a     a      0  11.973688       76
1     a     a      1   9.788948       66
2     a     a      2   9.371912       59
3     a     a      3  11.116768       32
4     a     b      4  10.347337       17
5     a     b      5  11.966324       76
6     a     b      6   9.272982       73
7     a     b      7   8.865021       34

def getCumArpi(df, group_variables, arpi_var, cumapri_var_new='cumarpi'):
  """get cumarpi variable for different types of group variables"""

  df = df.copy(deep=True)

  if len(group_variables) == 0:
    # no groupby variables
    df[cumapri_var_new] = np.cumsum(df[arpi_var])
  else:
    cumarpi = df.groupby(group_variables, group_keys=False).apply(lambda s: np.cumsum(s[arpi_var]))
    print cumarpi
    try:
      # groupby apply returns Series
      df[cumapri_var_new] = cumarpi
    except:
      # groupby apply returns DataFrame
      df[cumapri_var_new] = cumarpi.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

  return df

df_1 = getCumArpi(df, ['type1'], 'arpi')

print df_1

# returns a DataFrame and inserts it as a column anyways if using a column that already exists, but inserts it as all NaNs

arpi           0          1          2          3          4          5         6          7
type1
a      11.973688  21.762636  31.134548  42.251316  52.598654  64.564978  73.83796  82.702981
  type1 type2  index       arpi  cumarpi
0     a     a      0  11.973688      NaN
1     a     a      1   9.788948      NaN
2     a     a      2   9.371912      NaN
3     a     a      3  11.116768      NaN
4     a     b      4  10.347337      NaN
5     a     b      5  11.966324      NaN
6     a     b      6   9.272982      NaN
7     a     b      7   8.865021      NaN

df_2 = getCumArpi(df, ['type1'], 'arpi', cumapri_var_new='cumarpi_new')

print df_2

# returns a DataFrame but throws an error when inserting as a column, this triggers the except clause and correctly stacks it into a Series

arpi           0          1          2          3          4          5         6          7
type1
a      11.973688  21.762636  31.134548  42.251316  52.598654  64.564978  73.83796  82.702981
  type1 type2  index       arpi  cumarpi  cumarpi_new
0     a     a      0  11.973688       76    11.973688
1     a     a      1   9.788948       66    21.762636
2     a     a      2   9.371912       59    31.134548
3     a     a      3  11.116768       32    42.251316
4     a     b      4  10.347337       17    52.598654
5     a     b      5  11.966324       76    64.564978
6     a     b      6   9.272982       73    73.837960
7     a     b      7   8.865021       34    82.702981

df_3 = getCumArpi(df, ['type1', 'type2'], 'arpi')

print df_3

# returns a Series because the split-apply-combine methodology groups into more than one group and inserts correctly

0    11.973688
1    21.762636
2    31.134548
3    42.251316
4    10.347337
5    22.313661
6    31.586644
7    40.451665
Name: arpi, dtype: float64
  type1 type2  index       arpi    cumarpi
0     a     a      0  11.973688  11.973688
1     a     a      1   9.788948  21.762636
2     a     a      2   9.371912  31.134548
3     a     a      3  11.116768  42.251316
4     a     b      4  10.347337  10.347337
5     a     b      5  11.966324  22.313661
6     a     b      6   9.272982  31.586644
7     a     b      7   8.865021  40.451665
```

Comment: consider breaking this into two separate questions so they it's clear what constitutes an answer

Comment: the main thing is, when assigning a DataFrame to a DataFrame column, why does this not throw an error and assign all NaNs if the column already exists in the DataFrame? Since when creating a new column, an error is thrown because the shape does not match.